# Merge two lines into one using ID in Power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I'm using Power BI for visualize my data saved in a Mongo Database.

My records looks like that

```
'_id': 0,
'code_zone': "ABCD",
'type_zone': "Beautiful",
'all_coordinates': [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "one_coordinates": [10.11, 40.44]
        },
        "properties": {
            "limite_vertical_min": "L0",
            "limite_vertical_max": "L100"
        }
    }]
```

When I import data on Power BI, he divides my records into 3 "tables":

- my_collection
- my_collection.all_coordinates
- my_collection.all_coordinates.one_coordinates

Because I didn't know how can I fixe this issue, I selected this 3 tables and I linked them using id.

Actually, I can visualize that :

```
_id | code_zone | index_all_coordinates | index_one_coordinate | value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id0 | ABCD      | 1                     | 0                    | 10.11
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id0 | ABCD      | 1                     | 1                    | 40.44
```

I'm expecting to have that :

```
_id | code_zone | index_all_coordinates | value_x | value_y
------------------------------------------------------------
id0 | ABCD      | 1                     | 10.11   | 40.44
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it the good solution or I have to refactor my data before the import in Power BI ?
How can I merge this two lines into one with Power BI ?

Answer (score 0):

To get from the first table to the second, you can pivot on the `index_one_coordinate` column and then relabel those new columns `0` and `1` to `value_x` and `value_y`.